# MVC2 Multiple Model definition from linq to sql class VB.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, linq-to-sql

I call upon the VB ninjas out there. Here's my situation. I need to eventually be able to pass multiple models to a view. Currently I have a linq to sql class that, of course, has a bunch of generated model definitions. I need to make a model that implements multiple models. I somewhat understand how to do this in C#, but this project is testing my VB skillz.

Here's some snippets from my linq to sql models. I need to combine these two into one model to pass to the view.

Article model:

```
<Global.System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name:="dbo.Articles")>  _
Partial Public Class Article
    Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanging, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged

    Private Shared emptyChangingEventArgs As PropertyChangingEventArgs = New PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty)

    Private _ArticleID As Integer

    Private _ClassID As System.Nullable(Of Integer)

    Private _Title As String

    Private _ShortDescription As String

    Private _LongDescription As String

    Private _ByLine As String

    Private _ArticleDate As System.Nullable(Of Date)

    Private _SchoolClass As EntityRef(Of SchoolClass)
```

Staff model:

```
<Global.System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name:="dbo.Staff")>  _
Partial Public Class Staff
    Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanging, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged

    Private Shared emptyChangingEventArgs As PropertyChangingEventArgs = New PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty)

    Private _StaffID As Integer

    Private _ClassID As Integer

    Private _PositionID As System.Nullable(Of Integer)

    Private _StaffName As String

    Private _Position As EntityRef(Of Position)

    Private _SchoolClass As EntityRef(Of SchoolClass)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be missing the point of the question, but the first issue is that everything in these classes is `Private`. Maybe you're just showing the backing fields?

Assuming so, it seems like you just want to compose and expose some data from these objects through a presentation model:

```
Public Class StaffAndArticleViewModel
    Private _Article As Article
    Private _Staff As Staff

    Public Sub New(ByVal a As Article, ByVal s As Staff)
        _Article = a
        _Staff = s
    End Sub

    ' now you just expose everything that the view requires
    ' for example:

    Public Property StaffName As String
        Get
            Return _Staff.Staff
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            _Staff.Staff = Value
        End Set
    End Property
```

Comment: yep, those are the backing fields. This is definitely what I'm looking for. So when I define a new StaffAndArticleViewModel it should look something like this ?

Dim staffandarticle as new StaffAndArticleViewModel(a, b)

Comment: @keynone Yes, where `a` is an `Article` and `b` is a `Staff`. I made an assumption that you needed to expose one of each. You don't have to expose all the properties of both entities -- just what your view requires. You could also add properties that are "calculated" from values of the `Article` and `Staff` (these would probably be read-only).